# Swig is not detecting correctly the struct to call C++

Tags: c++, go, swig

I am trying to use a Golang structure in c++ code. To do so, I defined the same structure in both C++ header and in Golang, but when I try to run the project I get the following error:

```
./runme.go:22:32: cannot use (*Edge)(dataPtr) (value of type *Edge) as example.Edge value in argument to example.Process: *Edge does not implement example.Edge (missing method GetW)
```

My project has the following structure.

`./go.mod`:

```
module simple

go 1.20
```

`./runme.go`:

```
package main

import (
        "unsafe"
        "simple/example"
)

type Edge struct {
        X, Y int64
        W    float64
}

func main() {
        data := []Edge {
                {1,2,1.0},
                {1,3,4.0},
                {2,3,3.0},
                {2,4,0.5},
        }

        dataPtr := unsafe.Pointer(&data[0])
        example.Process((*Edge)(dataPtr),int64(len(data)), int64(4))
}
```

Then I have my package that contains the c++ code:

`./example/package.go`:

```
package example

import "C"
```

`./example/example.i`:

```
%module example

// Typemaps for Edge struct
%typemap(in) Edge {
    $1 = *($1_ltype*)($input);
}
%typemap(in) Edge* {
    $1 = *($1_ltype*)($input);
}

%typemap(out) Edge {
    $result = new $1_btype($1);
}

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"
```

`./example/example.h`:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

typedef struct Edge
{
        long int X, Y;
        double W;
} Edge;

void Process(Edge *G, long int M, long int N);

#endif
```

`./example/example.cpp`:

```
#include "example.h"
#include <iostream>

void Process(Edge *G, long int M, long int N) {
        // Do some work with the Edge list
        std::cout << "|V| = " << N << "  --  |E| = " << M << std::endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                std::cout << "(" << G[i].X << ", " << G[i].Y << ") = " << G[i].W << std::endl;
        }
}
```

I tried to implement the GetW and all other methods that it asks for, but at some point it asks for methods that I do not understand what they mean. I believe the problem might be with the typemap in the swig interface that is not connecting properly both structs, but I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: You don't need typemaps for `Edge`, just use the default typemaps. The problem is that your typemaps are incorrect, you can't transform a Go object to a C/C++ object with a simple cast.

Comment: I removed the `typemap`s from the `example.i` so it uses the default ones, but I still get the same error @Criminal_Affair_At_SO

Comment: Why do you redefine the `Edge` type in Go? Usually the SWIG definition is enough? I think that you are creating a different type with a similar name this way. I am sorry, I know SWIG very well, but I don't do Go. Have you seen https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Examples/go/simple ? It contains precisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to use my Go structure in my C++ code, that's why I was redefining it. But, now, I think that I might have understood wrongly the philosophy of SWIG. I'll rewrite my Golang code

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Using the higher-level language structure from SWIG is always tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the types in both languages as you have done.

Ignore the C++ type from SWIG:

```
%ignore Edge;
```

SWIG generates a Go wrapper with the Go signatures, this wrapper must have the Go `Edge` type declared, import it using:

```
%insert(go_wrapper) %{
// import here
%}
```

SWIG must also know to use the right type in the wrapper, use the special `gotype` typemap for this:

```
%typemap(gotype) Edge "root.Edge"
```

Remember to check the `example/example.go` file - it will have something that goes as:

```
func Process(arg1 Edge, arg2 int64, arg3 int64) {
```

This is the root of your problem. The `gotype` typemap should fix this.

Sorry, but I have but a very basic understanding of Go.

Comment: Ok, finally I managed to make it working. I needed to also add `%typemap(gotype) Edge* "*graph.Edge"`, so I could use pointers to pass the array/slice. Moreover, the `example/example.go` adds the import in a different position than the others, so I had to move it. Also, I was missing the `-c++` flag. Thank you very much!